# keycloak administration console navigating to wrong dns

Tags: keycloak

So I deploying keycloak in k8s, have it connected to a new fresh database, with an DNS. I am able to navigate to the instance of keycloak by using https://int-keycloak etc... , but when I click on admin console it navigates to the wrong DNS. Any ideas, cause not sure what is causing this

Adjust DNS , created new DNS and made sure everything matched on k8s template. Created fresh database to make sure it is not database related.